# AngularJS child components

Tags: angularjs

How is it possible to have nested components with AngularJS, ie:

```
var parentComponent = {
    template: `<div class='parent'>CHILD HERE</div>`
};

var childComponent = {
template: `<h1>Child Component</h1>`,
}

angular.module('demoApp', [])
.component('parent', parentComponent)
.component('child', childComponent)
```

The HTML would be:

```
<div ng-app="demoApp">
    <parent>
        <child></child>
    </parent>
</div>
```

The rendered result would be:
    `<div class='parent'><h1>Child Component</h1></div>`

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/2qbky4eu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using the `transclude` property.

```
var parentComponent = {
    template: `<div class='parent'><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></div>`,
    transclude: true
};

var childComponent = {
template: `<h1>Child Component</h1>`,
}

angular.module('demoApp', [])
.component('parent', parentComponent)
.component('child', childComponent)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/du4oLr9z/